# React: use Children.map to edit props and use functions as Children in the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use Children.map to edit props for each child and use functions as Children to pass params in the same time

**In React we can use Functions as Children Like that**

```
children({param1: 'coco', param2: 'bibi'})
```

And so we use it Like that

```
<Example>
  {({param1, param2}) => (<div>{param1}</div>)}
</Example>
```

**And if we want to edit props for each child we use this method**

```
{Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
        return cloneElement(child as ReactElement<any>, {
          param1: 'coucou',
        });
      })}
```

I want todo is like this in my situation

```
<Example>
  {({param1, param2}) => data.map(item=> <ExampleChild> {item.text} {param1} </ExampleChild>)}
</Example>
```

I want this case and also i want to add props to ExampleChild from Example
for example I want to pass a prop index to ExampleChild from Example directly

**So how we can do if we want to use both (functional children, edit children props) in the same time? please !**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `index` to `Example`'s child you should not use fragments which will be treated as a single child and `.map` won't work.

It should be in an array

```
export const Default = () => {
  return <Example>{({param1}) => [<Test>{param1}</Test>, <Test>hello2</Test>]}</Example>;
};
```

You can pass index via `cloneElement`

```
 function renderChildren() {
  const _children = children({ param1: 'foo' });
  return React.Children.map(_children, (child, idx) => {
    return cloneElement(child, {
      /* Add props here , if you want to passs it to ExampleChild */
      index: idx,
    });
  });
}
```

**Example.jsx**

```
function Example({ children }) {
  function renderChildren() {...}
  return <div>{renderChildren()}</div>
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry its not my case :(

I dont want to passe the props for each children but i want to pass param1 and param2 only one time for the big child

Comment: updated the answer, Please check.

Comment: Thanks for replying but still not what i need :( you can see my new response i tryed to more explain my case

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated my question. I will test it as soon as possible! Thanks a lot !

Comment: it doesnt work _children.map is not a function :( itryed like that

Comment: Does data contain more than 1 element ? can you console log and check the _children?

Comment: I updated my quetion with how i tested it and i loged the children

Answer (score 0):

iT works for me when i do like this

```
export const Parent = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  return <Box {...rest}>{children({ param1: 'fofo' })}</Box>;
};

export const ParentFragment = ({ children }) => {
  return Children.map(children, (child, idx) => {
    return cloneElement(child as ReactElement<any>, {
      index: idx,
    });
  });
};

export const Test = ({ index, children }) => {
  console.log({ index });

  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      {({param1}) => (
        <ParentFragment>
          <Test>hello {param1}</Test>
          <Test>hello2</Test>
        </ParentFragment>
      )}
    </Parent>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is working because you are traversing the React Fragemnt's children , which contains Test component

Comment: Do you think we have better solution todo that without fragment or array like your example ?

Comment: For returning children from a function, no there is no other way than using array to map over the elements. All elements should be grouped (Fragment) and iterate their children or it should be an array.

Comment: Yes I updated my solution I think maybe this is the cleanest way to do that